# Writing the correct formula for SugarCRM

Tags: formula, crm, sugarcrm, calculated-field

I am trying to automatically populate a field through a calculated field.

Just a quick background we distribute equipment with serials numbers. This equipment is sometimes returned. So some customers have multiple products each with different status of returned, shipped and installed.

I would like to transfer this serial number to a field on the contact through a calculated field only if the status is installed or shipped.

I have tried:

```
related($products,"serial"),",",(related($products,"status"))
```

and

```
related(contains(status,"installed)"products,"serial")
```

I need this for reporting reasons and would be greatly appreciated if you could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combination of `ifElse` and `equal` and `related` and `or`

As an example, the following Sugar Logic formula can be placed on a Contact record and will populate the field with the related account's name if the related account is of the type "Reseller." If the Account is of some other *account_type* then the field takes the value of "nope!"

```
ifElse(equal(related($accounts,"account_type"),"Reseller"),related($accounts,"name"),"nope!")
```

If you wanted to add another condition, or allow for another acceptable Account Type, build in an `or`

When you're writing lengthy Sugar Logic like this, I find it helpful to start writing it out with indentation using a text editor:

```
ifElse(
    or(
        equal(related($accounts,"account_type"),"Reseller"),
        equal(related($accounts,"account_type"),"Investor"),
    ),
    related($accounts,"name"),
    "nope!"
)
```

In some versions of Sugar I've had to remove the extra spacing but it seems like in 7.2.2.0 at least the editor actually allows *and preservers* the formatting, which is a pleasant surprise.